# Installing docker-ce fails

Tags: docker

I am trying to install docker-ce on a virtual server I am renting at Strato.de. The end of the installation process fails though. I have created an installation script that works perfectly when I execute it locally or in a locally run virtual machine.

Setup script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y \
     apt-transport-https \
     ca-certificates \
     curl \
     software-properties-common

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

sudo add-apt-repository -y \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce
```

The error on the virtual server at Strato.de (Ubuntu 16.04):

```
docker-ce (17.12.0~ce-0~ubuntu) wird eingerichtet ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mi 2018-01-03 05:58:08 CET; 15ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 30871 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 30871 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Memory: 38.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes docker-ce (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
liberror-perl (0.17-1.2) wird eingerichtet ...
git-man (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.3) wird eingerichtet ...
git (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.3) wird eingerichtet ...
patch (2.7.5-1) wird eingerichtet ...
Trigger für libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für systemd (229-4ubuntu21) werden verarbeitet ...
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Anyone with having the same experience? Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem meanwhile. Turns out Docker doesn't like virtualizations such as Virtuozzo which is heavily in use by the virtual servers at Strato.de. There apparently is no workaround for this other than changing to a provider that doesn't use Virtuozzo for virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

I think so. On running the startup command manually, there is an error, suggesting that multiple valid graphics options exist, please choose 1. By adding -s overlay2 to the startup script OPTS (/etc/init/docker.conf), this fired into life again.

i.e.:
script
        # modify these in /etc/default/$UPSTART_JOB (/etc/default/docker)
        DOCKERD=/usr/bin/dockerd
        DOCKER_OPTS=-s overlays2

Hope this helps
Pete