# Can't Install Docker due to this Error : W: Unable to read e - open (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: 20.04, docker

I'm trying to install docker in my redundant laptop, but the issue is I'm facing with this error no matter what I do in terminal: `W: Unable to read e - open (2: No such file or directory)`

This is the output from my terminal:

```
dennis@Titan:~$ sudo apt update
Get:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease [52.1 kB]
Hit:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Get:5 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]   
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease    
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Fetched 266 kB in 1s (228 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
22 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/source/Sources' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)
dennis@Titan:~$ sudo list -a docker -ce
sudo: list: command not found
dennis@Titan:~$ apt list -a docker -ce
W: Unable to read e - open (2: No such file or directory)
dennis@Titan:~$ ^C
dennis@Titan:~$ apt list -a docker -ce
W: Unable to read e - open (2: No such file or directory)
dennis@Titan:~$ sudo apt list -a docker -ce
W: Unable to read e - open (2: No such file or directory)
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong exactly? I already checked that the folder for /var/lib/apt/lists/partial already exists and is empty.

It does not matter if I use sudo at the front or not, so I guess its not an admin account related issue either.

Comment: Are you actually trying `apt list -a docker -ce`? Try instead: `apt list -a docker-ce` (no space before `-ce`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing docker-ce fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991723/installing-docker-ce-fails)

Comment: hey @artur, sorry just saw here. I guess that was the issue, and realised it after this post later. Thanks anyway!